# What I need to do to reopen my question?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, quality-improvement

I had a question: [What are the pros and cons of three ways to implement programming language?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/1602)

It is closed with **"This question needs to be more focused."** reason.

But what I need to do, to improve this question?

PS: this question had **+2, -4** votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand that decision either (especially without any comments indicating specifically what was considered wrong).

My guess is that the "*what are the pros and cons of [these] ways?*" is what is too general.

Perhaps narrowing it down to a single perspective would help.
(Make it with respect to ease of design and implementation, efficiency of the resulting product, ease of learning by the users, or … .)

Comment: I've rewrite my question, maybe now it can be reopened?